# Returning the index of a value in a Lua table

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have this table in lua:

```
local values={"a", "b", "c"}
```

is there a way to return the index of the table if a variable equals one the table entries?
say

```
local onevalue = "a"
```

how can I get the index of "a" or onevalue in the table without iterating all values?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The accepted answer works, but there is room for improvement:

- Why not exit the loop once the element is found?  And why bother copying the entire source table into a new throwaway table?
- Usually, this sort of function returns the *first* array index with that value, not an *arbitrary* array index with that value.

For arrays:

```
-- Return the first index with the given value (or nil if not found).
function indexOf(array, value)
    for i, v in ipairs(array) do
        if v == value then
            return i
        end
    end
    return nil
end

print(indexOf({'b', 'a', 'a'}, 'a'))  -- 2
```

For hash tables:

```
-- Return a key with the given value (or nil if not found).  If there are
-- multiple keys with that value, the particular key returned is arbitrary.
function keyOf(tbl, value)
    for k, v in pairs(tbl) do
        if v == value then
            return k
        end
    end
    return nil
end

print(keyOf({ a = 1, b = 2 }, 2))  -- 'b'
```

Comment: That is really important for large tables. well written

Answer (score 27):

There is no way to do that without iterating.

If you find yourself needing to do this frequently, consider building an inverse index:

```
local index={}
for k,v in pairs(values) do
   index[v]=k
end
return index["a"]
```

Comment: That's really a smart solution.

Answer (score -1):

If you use Lua for Roblox development, you can use the `table.find` method:

```
print(table.find({'a', 'b', 'c'}, 'b'))
```