# Lua Array with Numbers find if number is in Array

Tags: arrays, lua

So i am having an Array in Lua, lets say:

`local Array = {1, 8, 10, 15, 20, 30}`

so now i want to know if a specific number is in the Array. So if did this:

```
    local number = 4    

    if Array[number] then
       print("Is in Array")
    else 
        print("Not in Array")
    end
```

I want to know if 4 is part of the array. It isent so expected output is `Not in Array` but Lua takes the number as the position of the entery, there is an entery on position 4 so the output is `Is in Array`

How can i check if a specific number is part of the array without indexing numbers as strings?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38282234/returning-the-index-of-a-value-in-a-lua-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't do what you think it does. Let's walk through it:

```lua
local Array = {1, 8, 10, 15, 20, 30}
```

this is just syntactic sugar for

```lua
local Array = {[1] = 1, [2] = 8, [3] = 10, [4] = 15, [5] = 20, [6] = 30}
```

thus `Array[4]` is `15`. This is how arrays work: You *index* an array using an *index*. An *index* is not to be confused with the *value* this gives you. In this example, `4` is the index and `15` is the value.

What you want isn't an *array* but rather a *set*. You can easily build a set in Lua by using the values as keys and using truthy values in a table:

```lua
local set = {[1] = true, [8] = true, [10] = true, [15] = true, [20] = true, [30] = true}
```

if you find this awkward to type, just write yourself an utility to turn an array into a set:

```lua
local function make_set(array)
    local set = {}
    for _, val in ipairs(array) do
        set[val] = true
    end
    return set
end
set = make_set{1, 8, 10, 15, 20, 30}
```

You can then use this set to efficiently check whether it contains a number:

```lua
if set[number] then
    print"is in set"
else
    print"not in set"
end
```

Side notes:

- Alternatively to building a set, you could use a linear search. This would be less efficient if done multiple times and isn't even much more convenient to implement. Lua makes the use of a "set" as a special case of the table very easy.
- `Uppercase` in Lua is usually reserved for "class-like" tables, although there is no "official" naming convention.